# What is the meaning of "cin" in the phrases "petras omnes cin cum...."?

Tags: meaning

So I've been trying to figure out the Latin lyircs in "[Hellfire](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zW23CJPfvPY)" from the video game Final Fantasy XV. It's really hard to make out what they're saying, and the only part that I've managed to kind of figure out is from timestamp 0:26-0:46, which repeats this phrase consisting of what I assume to be 6 words:

> Petras omnes cin cum (?) petras

(Regarding the question mark, I don't know what the fifth word is. I assume it's a verb of some sort.)

I stumbled across *cin cum* by accident; I was just typing what I heard into Google translate and hoping something made sense. *Cin*, according to Google translate, means "smell of smoke" but you have to type that exact phrase in *English* to Latin to get the word *cin*. Trying to translate *cin* from Latin to English just gets you... *cin* in English. The phrase *[omnes cin cum](https://www.google.com/search?q=omnescincum&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS860US860&oq=omnescincum&aqs=chrome..69i57.17427j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on)* (link is a google search) appears twice? I haven't found any Latin dictionary that actually has this word though. Anyone know what *cin* means? Is it an inflection of some sort?

Comment: Are you sure the time is correct? I don't seem to be able to pick any words between 0:26-0:46 in the clip. It could just be that I'm not good at hearing words in anything a choir sings, especially when mixed below the instruments.

Comment: The two Google hits you got are character recognition errors. In the first example, the OCR software completely dropped the ball, in the second one, it somewhat understandably stumbled over an abbreviated *enim* in the phrase *omnes enim eum viderunt*.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta The timing is definitely correct, but I may have completely misheard the lyrics. The reason why I  thought the lyrics might be correct was because Google translates “Petras omnes cin cum” as “All the rocks and the smell of smoke” or something along those lines, which makes sense in reference to like “fire and brimstone” and “Hellfire”. But I could be wrong in the lyrics since Google translate isn’t exactly renowned for their translation accuracy.

Comment: Also, I know the composer’s style in this VG’s soundtrack to know that there definitely ARE Latin lyrics in the song, since a majority of the other songs with choir parts have Latin lyrics. Otherwise it’s just “ahhh”. How it’s recorded for 90% of the soundtrack makes it obnoxiously difficult to figure out the words though.

Comment: Did you see this written or did you hear it? How do you pronounce "cin"? As it stands, this is not Latin.

Comment: @fdb It seems to be pronounced "chin", but that doesn't sound very Latin to me.